# Include darknet Yolov3 for object detection

Tags: c++, visual-studio, solution, yolo

Unfortunately I am not very experienced with C++ and the handling of Visual Studio. I have to implement a C++ application, in which I can integrate yolo or darknet as a library and use it flexibly. I'm using Windows and Visual Studio 2015.

I have looked at the [following repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet). 
What I have tried so far:

- I have installed CUDA (although I want to run the model on the CPU for testing purposes), Cudnn and Opencv
- I opened the vs solution from `build\darknet\darknet_no_gpu.sln` from the AlexeyAb repo with Visual Studio. Inside the repo there are a lot of header and C-files :

[image]

- I also added my `opencv\build\include` path to the *Additional Include Directories*, the `opencv\x64\vc14\lib` to the *Additonal Library Directories* and the `opencv_world320.dll`file to the linker `Input` field.
- I also set **x64** and **Release**

Now, I don't know how to proceed. Just creating a `source.cpp` and do a `#include "darknet.h"` seems not to work. I get a lot of errors like: `darknet_no_gpu.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`.  In the repo it is mentioned at several places that you have to build the solution but what exactly does this mean or what exactly do I get afterwards and do with it?

Does anyone know how I could solve my problem? I'm really glad for any advice!

Comment: Any ideas   guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using Yolo v3 in a C++ application you can use the [Alexey AB darknet repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet). 
 Just build the `yolo_cpp_dll.sln` or the `yolo_cpp_dll_no_gpu.sln` in the `build/darknet` folder depending on whether you need GPU support or not. 
There's also an example console application provided in the repository, that already integrates the yolo dll and it's features (see `build/darknet/yolo_console_dll.sln`). 
You can find more information on how to get those solutions to work and how to use darknet as a dll library [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-use-yolo-as-dll-and-so-libraries). 
The C++ API of the yolo dll can be found [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/include/yolo_v2_class.hpp).

### To add the Yolo DLL to a VS project, you have to ...

... set Build to **Release x64** 
... configure following properties in "Configuration Properties" tab for **Release x64**:

- add the path of the folder of the header file (`yolo_v2_class.hpp`) under **Project->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories**
- add the path of the folder of the lib file (`yolo_cpp_dll.lib`) under **Project->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories**
- add `yolo_cpp_dll.lib` under **Project->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies**

... put `pthreadVC2.dll` and `yolo_cpp_dll.dll` close to your .exe file (you can find those dlls in `build/darknet/x64` if you already built the `yolo_cpp_dll.sln` or the `yolo_cpp_dll_no_gpu.sln`)

Thanks to [@glm_java](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8056117/glm-java) for fixing my runtime issue when using the yolo dll!

If you have further questions, on how to build or compile these solutions, feel free to ask me!

Comment: DO you know where to include the dll in visual Studio?

Comment: Sorry, for that mess
Please have a look at the edited solution

Comment: Do you have experiences running yolo on a raspberry Pi? If yes, I would appreciate it if you have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360030/best-algorithm-and-platform-to-run-object-detection-on-embedded-systems

Comment: Do I undestand correctly, that your main goal is it, to run a console application (either written in c++ or python) that performs object detection on a rasberry PI? 
If so, from what I've seen YOLOv3 is a good solution for fast object detection. The downside is, that it requires a lot of GPU to be that fast. So if you are on a rasberry PI, that isn't equipped with a high-end GPU, I would recommend you to to use YOLOv3-tiny, it's less accurate but way faster. Have a look [here](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) for a comparison of network performances.

Comment: yes that is correct. Great tip! But even with tiny yolo i have really low fps. Do you know if another model or some model in tensorflow is faster on embedded systems? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What hardware are you using for for object detection?

Comment: Raspberry PI 4 with 1 gb RAM and Camera Module v2.1

Comment: I think that you only have two options in that case: One is to add a GPU to your Rasberry PI, have a look [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/want-your-raspberry-pi-4-to-run-a-modern-graphics-card-this-engineers-working-on-it/). The other one is to set up a console application that uses remote Object Detection (The PI sends the image to a PC and the PC responds with the detection boxes). It depends whether you need a fast object detection (GPU attached to Pi) or whether performance doesn't matter (remote detection). However a remote detection doesn't have to be significantly slower.

Comment: @LRK I am trying to make single .exe and I am also trying to build yolo_cpp_dll.sln or yolo_console_dll.sln. HOwever, I failed to do so. I cannot find the yolo_cpp_dll.lib file. Is there any step by step tutorial for this? Please help me with this. I am using YOLOv4 Darknet.

Answer (score 1):

@LRK I got the same bad_alloc exception and I've solved using changing visual studio from Debug to Release mode. I hope it will work.