# Yolo algorithm for custom object dection with .cfg,.weights files of pre-trained in darknet

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I am doing a project for detecting a specific object. I found someone who already trained Yolo for that object. I managed to get .cfg and .weights files(there is also one more file with .names extension). Now could someone help me what to do? How to use Keras and detect objects in an image?

Answer (score 0):

As you already have YOLO weights and a YOLO trained model, I would recommend you to use darknet as a object detection framework (but you can use Kerase, pytorch, and so on too if you really want to).

For further steps it depends on what you want to do in the end, if a command line tool is enough I would recommend the [Alexey AB darknet repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) (if you are on windows, else you can use the [original darknet repo from pjreddie](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/wiki/YOLO:-Real-Time-Object-Detection)).
The Alexey AB repo has a very detailed tutorial for using it and setting it up. You will also find command line examples there too.
If you want to use YOLO in a console application you can have a look at the [use YOLO as DLL section](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-use-yolo-as-dll-and-so-libraries) of the AlexeyAB darknet repo, or [that answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61333534/7081171) for a more detailed instruction.

 Hope that helps!