# Use YoloV3 to detect objects in C++ project VS

Tags: c++, yolo, darknet

I follow one topic to install yolo for c++ project ([Include darknet Yolov3 for object detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61286151/include-darknet-yolov3-for-object-detection/62638921#62638921)), but I have one more question : I try to launch Yolov3 in my c++ project. I built the yolo_cpp_dll_no_gpu.sln (I don't have GPU), so I have darknet_no_gpu.exe

I would like to detect some objects on my frame from my webcam. I obtain my frame, but I don't know how to launch yolo detection in c++ project. Maybe it's similar to python commands, but I don't find the c++ syntax...

Can you help me please ?

edit: (I give more details)

- I need to use YoloV3 for hand detection on a c++ project on visual studio 2019.
- So I trained Yolov3 with python commands. I obtained my .weights file and the detection works when I launch this command on the cmd :

  > darknet_no_gpu detector demo data/obj.data cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg yolov3-tiny_last.weights
- Now, I would like to use this detection in VS project. I built **yolo_cpp_dll_no_gpu.sln** to obtain **darknet_no_gpu.exe** [yolo cpp dll no gpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wM7y.png)
- In my project, I had the path of the include and library in the properties [path in properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwEwI.png) and the dependence [dependence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h6wR.png)

So, my question is, what is the syntax to use yolo on my frame: `

```
VideoCapture cap(0); // open camera
    if (!cap.isOpened())  
        return -1;
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);

    for (;;) {
        cap >> frame;

        if (frame.empty())
        break;
```

`
because I can't use this one in VS

```
darknet_no_gpu detector demo data/obj.data cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg yolov3-tiny_last.weights frame
```

**edit 2:**
Hello,
After some research with your help, I have 1 more problem...
Here is my code:

```
    #include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace dnn;
using namespace std;

// Initialize the parameters
float confThreshold = 0.5; // Confidence threshold
float nmsThreshold = 0.4;  // Non-maximum suppression threshold
int inpWidth = 416;  // Width of network's input image
int inpHeight = 416; // Height of network's input image
vector<string> classes;

// Remove the bounding boxes with low confidence using non-maxima suppression
void postprocess(Mat& frame, const vector<Mat>& out);

// Draw the predicted bounding box
void drawPred(int classId, float conf, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, Mat& frame);

// Get the names of the output layers
vector<String> getOutputsNames(const Net& net);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Load names of classes
    string classesFile = "obj.names";
    ifstream ifs(classesFile.c_str());
    string line;
    while (getline(ifs, line)) classes.push_back(line);

    // Give the configuration and weight files for the model
    String modelConfiguration = "yolov3-tiny.cfg";
    String modelWeights = "yolov3-tiny_last.weights";

    // Load the network
    Net net = readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights);
    net.setPreferableBackend(DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV);
    net.setPreferableTarget(DNN_TARGET_CPU);

    // Open a video file or an image file or a camera stream.
    string outputFile;
    //VideoCapture cap;
    VideoWriter video;
    Mat frame;
    Mat blob, ex;

    VideoCapture cap(0); // ouvre la camera par défaut
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check si succès
        return -1;  

    for (;;) {
        // get frame from the video
        cap >> frame;
        cvtColor(frame, ex, COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);

        cout << frame.size << endl;
        imshow("e", ex);
        // Stop the program if reached end of video
        if (frame.empty()) {
            cout << "Done processing !!!" << endl;
            cout << "Output file is stored as " << outputFile << endl;
            waitKey(3000);
            break;
        }
        // Create a 4D blob from a frame.
        blobFromImage(frame, blob, 1 / 255.0, Size(inpWidth, inpHeight), Scalar(0, 0, 0), true, false);

        //Sets the input to the network
        net.setInput(blob);

        // Runs the forward pass to get output of the output layers
        vector<Mat> outs;
        net.forward(outs, getOutputsNames(net));

        // Remove the bounding boxes with low confidence
        postprocess(frame, outs);

        // Put efficiency information. The function getPerfProfile returns the overall time for inference(t) and the timings for each of the layers(in layersTimes)
        vector<double> layersTimes;
        double freq = getTickFrequency() / 1000;
        double t = net.getPerfProfile(layersTimes) / freq;
        string label = format("Inference time for a frame : %.2f ms", t);
        putText(frame, label, Point(0, 15), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, Scalar(0, 0, 255));

        // Write the frame with the detection boxes
        Mat detectedFrame;
        frame.convertTo(detectedFrame, CV_8U);

        imshow("f", frame);

        Sleep(3000);

    }

    cap.release();

    return 0;
}

// Remove the bounding boxes with low confidence using non-maxima suppression
void postprocess(Mat& frame, const vector<Mat>& outs)
{
    vector<int> classIds;
    vector<float> confidences;
    vector<Rect> boxes;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < outs.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Scan through all the bounding boxes output from the network and keep only the
        // ones with high confidence scores. Assign the box's class label as the class
        // with the highest score for the box.
        float* data = (float*)outs[i].data;
        for (int j = 0; j < outs[i].rows; ++j, data += outs[i].cols)
        {
            Mat scores = outs[i].row(j).colRange(5, outs[i].cols);
            Point classIdPoint;
            double confidence;
            // Get the value and location of the maximum score
            minMaxLoc(scores, 0, &confidence, 0, &classIdPoint);
            if (confidence > confThreshold)
            {
                int centerX = (int)(data[0] * frame.cols);
                int centerY = (int)(data[1] * frame.rows);
                int width = (int)(data[2] * frame.cols);
                int height = (int)(data[3] * frame.rows);
                int left = centerX - width / 2;
                int top = centerY - height / 2;

                classIds.push_back(classIdPoint.x);
                confidences.push_back((float)confidence);
                boxes.push_back(Rect(left, top, width, height));
            }
        }
    }

    // Perform non maximum suppression to eliminate redundant overlapping boxes with
    // lower confidences
    vector<int> indices;
    NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThreshold, indices);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i)
    {
        int idx = indices[i];
        Rect box = boxes[idx];
        drawPred(classIds[idx], confidences[idx], box.x, box.y,
            box.x + box.width, box.y + box.height, frame);
    }
}

// Draw the predicted bounding box
void drawPred(int classId, float conf, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, Mat& frame)
{
    //Draw a rectangle displaying the bounding box
    rectangle(frame, Point(left, top), Point(right, bottom), Scalar(255, 178, 50), 3);

    //Get the label for the class name and its confidence
    string label = format("%.2f", conf);
    if (!classes.empty())
    {
        CV_Assert(classId < (int)classes.size());
        label = classes[classId] + ":" + label;
    }

    //Display the label at the top of the bounding box
    int baseLine;
    Size labelSize = getTextSize(label, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1, &baseLine);
    top = max(top, labelSize.height);
    rectangle(frame, Point(left, top - round(1.5 * labelSize.height)), Point(left + round(1.5 * labelSize.width), top + baseLine), Scalar(255, 255, 255), FILLED);
    putText(frame, label, Point(left, top), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, Scalar(0, 0, 0), 1);
}

// Get the names of the output layers
vector<String> getOutputsNames(const Net& net)
{
    static vector<String> names;
    if (names.empty())
    {
        //Get the indices of the output layers, i.e. the layers with unconnected outputs
        vector<int> outLayers = net.getUnconnectedOutLayers();

        //get the names of all the layers in the network
        vector<String> layersNames = net.getLayerNames();

        // Get the names of the output layers in names
        names.resize(outLayers.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < outLayers.size(); ++i)
            names[i] = layersNames[outLayers[i] - 1];
    }
    return names;
}
```

So it would be working, but I obtain a gray windows with imshow. Like on the picture [gray window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PemO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [what kinds of questions you can ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [what kind of questions to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). In particular, you must show us your code and some effort to resolve your issue.

Comment: Could you clarify the question- are you trying to use yolo with your own C++ code or are you having trouble getting yolo to run?

Comment: https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/ maybe this tutorial could be helpful

Comment: Thank you for your question. I understood what you want. However I am also looking for a solution for what you want. If you have finished your project I would like to know to you finished it.